# NSDictionary setting to nil when passed to another class (IOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsdictionary

I am passing an NSDictionary object from one view class to another as I transition from a table view to a normal view to show details:

Passing Controller:

```
[tweetController setTweet:tweet];
```

Receiving Controller.h:

```
@interface TweetViewController : UIViewController {
    NSDictionary *tweet;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *tweet;
```

Receiving Controller.m:

```
@implementation TweetViewController

@synthesize tweet = _tweet;
```

I then try to use this information to set the properties of some fields in my view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tweetLabel.text = [_tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
}
```

The result is a blank label and if I inspect the value of _tweet at this stage it is nil.

I originally had a method which set the value of tweet which I called at the same location as I am now setting the value. If I inspected the value at this stage it was fine.

I presume that the automagic setter through @synthasize is working, but somewhere else the value is being lost.

Sorry this is my first objective C anything! Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: You're inspecting your "tweet" ivar whereas the "tweet" property is synthesized to the "_tweet" ivar. That's why.

Comment: @H2CO3 Good catch! Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using your "tweet" instance variable, whereas the "tweet" property is synthesized to the "_tweet" variable.

Comment: Hi not sure I fully understand (apologies). 

`tweetLabel.text = [_tweet objectForKey:@"text"];`

Isn't this looking at the instance variable?

Comment: @synthesize tweet=_tweet; means when you call setTweet, then _tweet will have the newly set value, NOT tweet.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably calling the setTweet method **after**  viewDidLoad executes.
I usually pass this kind of thing into a custom init method.
Alternatively, you could do the set before pushing the detail VC onto the nav stack.

Comment: Hi I thought this too, so I put a breakpoint on both and the order is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that tweetLabel isn't nil?

I've made a few corrections & optimisations to your code. You don't need to declare ivars in the header file anymore, they are generated automatically by `@synthesize`

`- (void)dealloc;` is only needed if you're not using ARC.

```
//.h
@interface TweetViewController : UIViewController


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *tweet;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tweetLabel

@end


//.m
@implementation TweetViewController

@synthesize tweet = _tweet;
@synthesize tweetLabel = _tweetLabel;


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tweetLabel.text = [self.tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [_tweet release];
    [_tweetLabel release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Note: `strong` is equivalent to `retain`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Rayfleck's answer, since you are new to Objective-C, your custom init method could look like this:

In TweetViewController.h:

```
- (id)initWithTweet:(NSDictionary*)tweet;
```

In TweetViewController.m:

```
- (id)initWithTweet:(NSDictionary*)tweet
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
       _tweet = tweet;
    }
    return self;
}
```

and then in your passing controller you'd allocate and initialize like this:

```
TweetViewController *tvc = [[TweetViewController alloc] initWithTweet:myTweet];
```